# Group by a column to find the most frequent value in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Group by a column to find most frequent value in another column.
Example:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ['green','green','green','blue','blue','blue'],'col2': ['gx','gx','ow','nb','nb','mj']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

gives:

```
col1   col2
green  gx
green  gx
green  ow
blue   nb
blue   nb
blue   xv
```

results:

for `green` to have `gx` and for `blue` to have `nb`

Comment: I may not have been clear enough but i don't want this. I want to keep the rows that have the most frequent value only.

Comment: Sorry, I realised it later :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and select first value of index:

```
df = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index()
print (df)
    col1 col2
0   blue   nb
1  green   gx
```

Or add [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].value_counts().reset_index(name='v')

df = df.drop_duplicates('col1')[['col1','col2']]
print (df)
    col1 col2
0   blue   nb
2  green   gx
```

Or use [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html) and select first value by positions by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
df = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]).reset_index()
print (df)
    col1 col2
0   blue   nb
1  green   gx
```

EDIT:

Problem is with only `NaN`s groups:

```
d = {'col1': ['green','green','green','blue','blue','blue'],
     'col2': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'nb','nb','mj']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

f = lambda x: np.nan if x.isnull().all() else x.value_counts().index[0]
#or
#f = lambda x: next(iter(x.value_counts().index), np.nan)
#another solution
#f = lambda x: next(iter(x.mode()), np.nan)
df = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(f).reset_index()
print (df)
    col1 col2
0   blue   nb
1  green  NaN
```

Comment: I tried to apply it to a dataframe other than the example and it says: `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`. Do you know why?

Comment: @user10288621 - Sure, give me a sec.

Comment: @user10288621 - Check edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GroupBy` + `transform` with [`pd.Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html) and then [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

With this solution, the index from your original dataframe is maintained. It assumes there is only one mode, and so filters for one mode per group.

```
modes = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
res = df[df['col2'] == modes].drop_duplicates()

print(res)

    col1 col2
0  green   gx
3   blue   nb
```